# Can I index columns to speed up a slow join on date range

Tags: postgresql, join, indexing

Issue: I've got a sub-query which does an inner join on a calendar table and a stock table which is slow and needs speeding up. Current speed of about 120 seconds.

Generally, the aim is to use this dataset to calculate what the stock levels were of each product on every day of the year.

To spped it up, can I place an index on the calendar's daily date field (the daily_date is unique) to speed up the query? And/or the start_date and end_dates timestamp fields? I'm unclear on best practice for indexing.

The calendar table has a daily date field which is joined to the stock table on the range between start_date and end_date:

```
select        dd.daily_date, t.stock_product_name, t.stock_id
          , (12 * extract('years' from (t.warehouse_eta - dd.date_field))) + (30 * extract('months' from (t.warehouse_eta - dd.date_field))) + (extract('days' from (t.warehouse_eta - dd.date_field))) as delivery_time
from          a.dates dd
inner join    stock_availability t on ((dd.daily_date >= t.start_date) and (dd.daily_date <= t.end_date or t.end_date is null))
where         dd.daily_date >= '2017-01-01' and dd.daily_date <= current_date
```

(I've a lot of windows tabs open regarding indexing at the moment but it is slow reading. Any intro links also appreciated.)

Comment: From experimenting it seems to be about 20% quicker if I index the dates table daily_date column.

Comment: Also updating the end_date to a future date instead of null seems to add an increase in speed, through a simpler join from `(dd.daily_date <= t.end_date or t.end_date is null))` to `(dd.daily_date <= t.end_date)`

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query. Add it to the question.